# ProgrammingError: relation "_unknown" does not exist LINE 1

Tags: python, odoo

I'm getting this error in Odoo:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "_unknown" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "_unknown".id FROM "_unknown" ORDER BY "_unknown"."id...
```

**`hotel` class:**

```
class obj_ghotel(osv.osv):
        _name = "obj.ghotel"
        _description = "Objet ghotel"
        ...
        'id_ville':fields.many2one('obj.ville','ville', 
selection=_get_selection),
```

**`ville` class:**

```
class obj_ville(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.ville"
    _description = "Objet ville"
    _rec_name = 'nom_ville'
    ...
        'id_hotel':fields.one2many('obj.ghotel','id_ville'),
```

I have to restart the Odoo services and PostgreSQL to fix the problem. I think the problem is in the dependencies. I'm stuck... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you know that you are using the old api (OpenERP v6.1)?

Comment: @ChesuCR Yes i know , I'm a beginner at odoo and i'm creating my first module for a small school project.

Comment: This problem is related to missing dependencies. Check if you have added dependant module in __openerp__.py file properly or not.

Comment: Yes i fixed it thnx man

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem, i only added that module name (ville) into openerp.py file in depend section..

Answer (score 0):

you're using a base module but you didn't add it to the **manifest**.py 'depends' values